# Get a value from a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I have a User control with a button. when click on the button create a random number. I want use this number in Main Window. I use user control for 3 time in my Main Window. but I can't get the number in main window. I use MVVM.
Please help me!

UserControl.xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="test.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"

             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <local:UserControl1VM/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=txt}"/>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Show Num" Command="{Binding Path=AddNum}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

User Contorl View Model

```
public class UserControl1VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _txt;

    public string txt
    {
        get { return _txt; }
        set
        {
            _txt = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("txt");
        }
    }
    public RelayCommand AddNum { get; set; }


    public UserControl1VM()
    {
        AddNum = new RelayCommand(DoAddNum);
    }

    private void DoAddNum(object obj)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        txt = random.Next(0, 100).ToString();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<UniformGrid Rows="4">
    <local:UserControl1 Margin="20"/>
    <local:UserControl1 Margin="20"/>
    <local:UserControl1 Margin="20"/>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2" Margin="20">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sum}"/>
        <Button Content="Sum" Command="{Binding Path=AddSum}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</UniformGrid>
```

Main Window View Model

```
public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Sum;

    public string Sum
    {
        get { return _Sum; }
        set
        {
            _Sum = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Sum");
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand AddSum { get; set; }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        AddSum = new RelayCommand(DoAddSum);
    }


    private void DoAddSum(object obj)
    {

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

RelayCommand.cs

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private string v;

    private Action<object> MyAction { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> MyAction)
    {
        this.MyAction = MyAction;
    }

    public RelayCommand(string v)
    {
        this.v = v;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MyAction(parameter);
    }
}
```

I want When click on "Sum" show Sum of 3 numbers in the text block.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, Ali. In order for us to help you, you need to show us the relevant code. Even if it does not do, what you want, give us your best try. As is, this question is likely going to be closed. You may want to have a look into [ask].

Comment: Add an appropriate property to your UserControl. Most likely a dependency property.

Comment: Please note that a UserControl should not have its own, private view model. Such a view model would be disconnected from the view model structure of the application. Instead, the UserControl should expose bindable properties that are bound to properties of a view model that is passed by value inheritance of the DataContext property, which is set at the Window or Page that contains the UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestions

- change 'sum' and 'txt' property types to int - sum up is easier on numbers ;-)
- use a composite pattern on your ViewModels. Let the MainWindow view model consist of three UserControlVM's.

**Changes**

1.) Changes to MainWindow.xaml

```
<UniformGrid Rows="4">
    <UniformGrid.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVM/>
    </UniformGrid.DataContext>
    <local:UserControl1 Margin="20" DataContext="{Binding UserControlVM1}"/>
    <local:UserControl1 Margin="20" DataContext="{Binding UserControlVM2}"/>
    <local:UserControl1 Margin="20" DataContext="{Binding UserControlVM3}"/>
```

2.) **Remove** from UserControl1.xaml:

```
<Grid.DataContext>
        <local:UserControl1VM/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

3.) Change MainWindowVM.cs

```
    public class MainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly List<UserControl1VM> childVms;

    public UserControl1VM UserControlVM1 { get; set; }
    public UserControl1VM UserControlVM2 { get; set; }
    public UserControl1VM UserControlVM3 { get; set; }

    public MainWindowVM()
    {
        childVms = new List<UserControl1VM>()
        {
            new UserControl1VM(),
            new UserControl1VM(),
            new UserControl1VM(),
        };

        UserControlVM1 = childVms[0];
        UserControlVM2 = childVms[1];
        UserControlVM3 = childVms[2];

        AddSum = new RelayCommand(DoAddSum);
    }

    private int _Sum;


    public int Sum
    {
        get { return _Sum; }
        set
        {
            _Sum = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Sum");
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand AddSum { get; set; }


    private void DoAddSum(object obj)
    {
        childVms.ForEach(vm => Sum += vm.txt);
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```